# Using double pointers, casting from **void. (Unhandled exception 0xC0000005: Access violation)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am dynamically creating an array of objects (Image objects). I have a function that exports a double pointer to said objects. This return is being passed up to some code that doesn't know about my Image class, so I'm casting my double image pointer as a double void pointer. This code later passes that same double void pointer back down into some code that is aware of my Image class. Finally, I will recast the double void pointer back to a double Image pointer and do stuff with the objects.

The problem is I'm getting a familiar error (Unhandled exception 0xC0000005).

Here's where the error is occurring -

```
void Game::drawState0(void** vPtr)
{
Image **iptr = (Image**)(vPtr);

(*iptr)[0].doStuff(); //this line blows up
(*iptr)[1].doStuff();
(*iptr)[2].doStuff(); 
}
```

The odd thing is, it looks like the address I'm passing around is OK. So why is there an access violation?

[image]

UPDATE: additional requested information

[image]

UPDATE2: code that calls drawState0 (with unrelated bits taken out)

```
void **imgPtr;
imgPtr = update();
renderImage(imgPtr);
```

definition for renderImage:

```
void Top::renderImage(void** vPtr)
{
render(vPtr);           // call render() in derived object
}
```

definition for render in derived object

```
void Top::render(void** vPtr)
{
switch (var)
{
    case 0:
    {
        drawState0(vPtr); 
        break;
    }
    //....
```

UPDATE 3: Creation of imgPtr (this is the function that passes the double pointer back up after recasting it

```
Image **st0 = new Image*[3];

for (char j = 0; j<= 2; j++)
{
    st0[j] = new Image; 
}

//..
imgPtr = (void**)st0;
return imgPtr;
```

Comment: It looks like access violation to me, is your vPtr properly allocated?

Comment: Please post a (short) complete program giving the exception. In general, if you only post part of a program, the possibility that the problem is somewhere else is always there (in this case, it seems like it is), and we'd just be wasting our time reading your question.

Comment: Duke, the whole program is a few klines. I've stepped through with the debugger and found the line that breaks. It's commented in the original post. I've also attached a VS2010 screenshot showing the states of the relevant entities right before the bad line is executed. What else can I provide in lieu of the whole program that would be helpful?

Comment: @DimitriosBouzas What does "properly allocated" mean? The watch window displays the value I would expect to see.

Comment: @ooga - that is not correct.  A void pointer is a valid concept, and is itself an address which needs to be stored somewhere.  So you can have a pointer to the location in which is stored a pointer to a void type, ie, a void **.

Comment: @user2864293 I mean if (*iptr)[0] has being allocated at all or is an arbitrary memory location that doesn't belong to your program.

Comment: @user2864293 0x002c9b10 may be a valid address, but does it *contain* data which is a valid address, pointing to an object having a doStuff() method?  You should click on the little expand (+) widget.

Comment: @user2864293 One of the first things you should learn about programming (especially in C++) is that the line on which the error happens isn't necessarily the line that's the problem. You definitely shouldn't post anywhere close to a few thousand lines of code here, but you could remove parts of the code not applicable to the problem, and replace some code with the hard-coded result of the execution of that code until you get down to something of postable size.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think it does! I'll edit the original post to provide an updated SS

Comment: @ChrisStratton You're right. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what I'm seeing but if `vPtr` is an array of pointers as I believe it is, you want to do this instead:

```
iptr[0]->doStuff();
iptr[1]->doStuff();
iptr[2]->doStuff();
```

Comment: Wow. That worked. What's the difference? *iptr[0] should still give me an object that I an use to execute doStuff() correct? VS2010 even autocompletes "doStuff()" for me when I try it that way.

Comment: Well, you are doing like `(*iptr)[1]`, so you are using the first element in `iptr` as the array, and not `iptr` itself. Theres your problem right here.

Comment: Hm, I'm assuming the following:
1) **iptr is the pointer to the pointer of images
2) *iptr[j] is the address of image j

Is this not true? As I mentioned, when I type "*iptr[0]." VS2010 starts to autocomplete for me as if it were an object

Comment: It's all a matter of synthax. `(*iptr)` fetches the first pointer in `iptr`, and that should be the pointer to an `Image` object, but instead you are using it as an array of `Image` objects. The synthax `->` exists to simplify this. It looks like you are trying to avoid the use of `->` for some reason, and in the end you create confusion and make it poorly readable. Don't do it.

Comment: `(*iptr)[1].doStuff()` is equivalent to `iptr[0][1].doStuff()`, and `iptr[1]->doStuff()` is equivalent to `iptr[1][0].doStuff()`.  This is why I was keen to see how you set the pointer up originally.

Comment: @user2864293 why don't you transit it as `Image**` in your code instead of converting it from/to `void**` everywhere?

Comment: Heh, so `image[n][0]` is indeed what you want. Any reason you didn't just have the function take `Image **`?   If you really do want to use `void`, then just `void *` would be fine and well-defined.

Comment: @Havenard The code that I'm passing the double pointer up to doesn't know about Image objects. I figured casting/recasting as void would get around that.

Comment: If it really doesn't then `new Image` wouldn't work. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can forward-declare, `struct Image;`, in code that can't see the full definition of the `Image` class/struct

Comment: @Havenard that part is done within a class that knows about Image. The Images are created dynamically (so they don't go out of scope and disappear). They are passed up to a class that doesn't know about Images. Later on, the code returns to a place that needs to use these images to do something. That's why I figured I'd use the pointers w/ void casting. I can create objects that can be used within multiple functions, and then delete them when they are no longer necessary. I hope my motivations were clear!

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-portable conversion: `Image **iptr = (Image**)(vPtr);`.

`void **` is not a "generic double pointer". Only `void *` is the generic pointer.

If your implementation uses the same size and representation for `Image *` and `void *`, then the code might work anyway.

My guess would be that you didn't set the pointer up correctly  in the call to `drawState0`. For example, you cast a 2-D array. Can you show the code that calls this function?

My advice would be to re-design the interface to not use `void **`.

Comment: I'll post the code you requested. Also, why is the conversion non portable? Can you please elaborate on your last sentence, I'm not entirely sure what it means.

Comment: It's non-portable because `void **` must point to a `void *`. When you write `*vPtr`, you access the bytes corresponding to this `void *` as if it were an `Image *`, which is undefined behaviour since this is not a well-defined pair of types for memory aliasing.  It's analogous to `void foo(double *d) { int *bar = (int *)d; }` and running into trouble when `foo` was invoked as `double x; foo(&x);`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb In the end we are talking about pointers here, and as you should know all pointers have the same size and stuff. As long as he is converting it to the correct type, the inputted type and conversion itself are irrelevant.

Comment: "all pointers have the same size and stuff" - not necessarily. `sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(other_type *)` may be different; and even if they were the same, they could have different representations.

Comment: @OP, you need to show the code that creates the pointer. Your "update 2" just shows it being copied around after the `update()` function (presumably) creates it, and you didn't show the code for `update()`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sorry but can you give me one exemple of how two pointers have different sizes? Because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Havenard, can you give a proof that they all have the same size, on every system there ever was and will be?

Comment: Pointers are just memory addresses after all, and that being said they have 4 bytes for 32-bit architecture and 8 for 64-bit architectures, and thats all. You will never find pointers of two different sizes inside the same code. You cannot have `sizeof(void *)` one size and at the same time `sizeof(other_type *)` with a different one in the same program.

Comment: Pointers aren't just memory addresses; they are a memory address plus type information about what is stored at that address. The type information doesn't use any storage on typical systems, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist; it's usually resolved at compile time, but doesn't have to be. Also, I've programmed on a system where `sizeof(void *)` was `3` , and some other pointers had size `2`. The third byte remembered what sort of pointer it came from, so that the pointer didn't compare equal with other 2-byte pointers that pointed to the same offset within a different memory page.

Comment: If that even exists then I believe you are talking about a rather very specific and probably obsolete architecture here. Do you know any relevant system that behaves like that?

Comment: No, but in my experience of porting code to multiple systems (or updating the compiler version or brand on the same system), it's preferable to obey the Standard even if you can't foresee a problem at the time.  In this case it is trivial to change the code so that it does not rely on the size and representation of the pointer.